# How to refresh a ListBox in subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform which displays the records in a table called devices. It uses a ListBox control to display a list of devices which can be clicked on to select specific records. The details are displayed in the rest of the form.

[image]

The main form is a ComboBox control that with a list of the available NetworkIds. My goal is to be able to select a networkId so that it only displays devices in the ListBox with a matching foreign key.

[image]

The number of records in the subform does change (4 devices for network 1), and if I display the subform as a datasheet it appears to be working. The only problem is the ListBox doesn't update and it continues to show every device.

I have tried refreshing and re-querying the subform using the OnChange event for the ComboBox.

Here's all I tried in the OnChange event:

```
Private Sub Combo1_Change()
    Me.DeviceManagement.Requery
    Me.DeviceManagement.Form.Requery
    Me.DeviceManagement.Form.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Me.DeviceManagement.Form.YourListBoxControl.Requery`

Comment: No luck with that, I don't think re-query effects it at all. Is there a command that I can use to totally 'reboot' a subform?